# Statistical Test for Embedding?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, statistical-significance, clustering

I have a bunch of labeled objects. Let's say there are K classes altogether. Now suppose every object is mapped to a data point in R^n, or in other words, is embedded in R^n. Ideally a good embedding means objects with the same class label should be close to each other. Is there any statistical test I can use here?

Comment: I see some answers in the "Related" column to the right, such as [Using statistical significance test to validate cluster analysis results](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18706) .  Have you searched our site for related questions?

Answer (score 1):

A simple (but imperfect) metric is the ratio of `within cluster sum of squares` to `between cluster sum of squares`.

Ideally this number is small, because objects within a cluster are close together, and objects not in the same cluster are far apart.

It can be costly to compute, however, as you need to calculate pairwise distances between all your objects.

You could approximate this by funding cluster centers, and then computing distances from the centers.

/edit This paper describes a wider range of statistical tests for clustering you could use: http://datamining.rutgers.edu/publication/internalmeasures.pdf.  I've gotten good results from the Calinski-Harabasz index in the past.